# What is the difference between "Computer science" and "Informatics"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I could not find any difference... or at least no good source that definitely distinguishes both.

I tried:

- Wikipedia ([Informatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatics) has a redirect to Computer Science), so I guess the only difference is the context in which both are used
- Google:

  - [University of California](http://www.informatics.uci.edu/qa/index.php#ugrad02):

    - Computer Science: internal features, structure and behavior of computer systems
    - Informatics: relationship between what is inside the computer and what is outside (What does this mean? I study ... well, I thought it would be called "Computer Science", but I'm not sure now. )
  - [forum.wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=7587&s=4f1c643670a344a153fccf5bbca5ec38&p=53232#post53232):

    - Computer Science: software engineering, algorithms
    - Informatics: installing new software, upgrades,networks LAN WANS, firewalls
- [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=informatik&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on): Both are translated with "Informatik" in German.
- English.StackExchange.com: No result

Comment: The same question was asked on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27573/2818) where it got what I think is a [very good answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/27609/2818).

Answer (score 2):

In the link to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatics) that you provide, the very first sublisting gives a definition of **informatics**

> a broad academic field encompassing computer science, human-computer interaction, information science, information technology, algorithms, areas of mathematics (especially mathematical logic and category theory), and social sciences that are involved

This definition clearly includes *computer science* as a subset of *informatics*, but goes on to list other topics that are beyond the scope of pure *computer science*, such as *social sciences that are involved*.

While a full degree program in *computer science* might require a student to take industrial psychology (or something similar), the psychology course itself would not be considered *computer science*. If it focused on the human handling and interpretation of data, it might be considered *informatics*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you are; according to an article in the magazine *Communications of the ACM* titled "[Why an Informatics Degree?](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/2/69363-why-an-informatics-degree)":

> The term "informatics" has different definitions depending on where it
>   is used. In Europe, for instance, computer science is referred to as
>   informatics. In the U.S., however, informatics is linked with applied
>   computing, or computing in the context of another domain.

Comment: "In Europe ... computer science is referred to as informatics." This would have been my answer.  Using the term *informatics* in the US is still fairly rare.

Answer (score 0):

Informatics is a broad academic field consisting of computer science,information science and information technology together with a cognate, that is a secondary field of study in which informatics is applied such as biology,chemistry and physics.

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up?